# create proper types in createcontext react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics, react-typescript

getting and error from types after creating a context

this is how i handle the createContext, im new to typescript:

```
export const ZoomContext = createContext<ZoomContextType>({
  zoom: 20,
  setZoom: (zoom: number) => {},
});

const ContextProvider = ({ children }: PropChildren) => {
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(20);
  return (
    <ZoomContext.Provider value={{ zoom, setZoom, }}>
      {children}
    </ZoomContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

im expecting not getting this error

```
Argument of type '(prevZoom: any) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345)menuComponent.tsx(17, 13): Did you mean to call this expression? Parameter 'prevZoom' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006) (parameter) prevZoom: any
```

in this lines of code

```
const handleZoomIn  = () => {
    setZoom((prevZoom) => prevZoom + 1 );
  };
  const handleZoomOut = () => {
    setZoom((prevZoom) => prevZoom - 1);
  };
```

the logic works, the context works, the typescript doesnt, thank u in advance for your time

Comment: `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>`